# How to fill timestamp gaps in a Postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, gaps-and-islands

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE channel1m (
  ts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  itemId BIGINT,
  value BIGINT
)
```

in which a row *may* be inserted each **minute**, per itemId, as follows:

```
ts                    itemId         value
2012-12-03 15:29:00   100            1
2012-12-03 15:30:00   100            2
2012-12-03 15:30:00   101            0
2012-12-03 15:32:00   100            1
2012-12-03 15:32:00   101            1
```

I can't find a way (without creating additional tables) to write a query that fills the time gaps (for example, 15:29:00 for itemId 101, and 15:31:00 for both items) by returning `NULL` in value.

The expected resultset would be:

```
ts                    itemId         value
2012-12-03 15:29:00   100            1
2012-12-03 15:29:00   101            NULL
2012-12-03 15:30:00   100            2
2012-12-03 15:30:00   101            0
2012-12-03 15:31:00   100            NULL
2012-12-03 15:31:00   101            NULL
2012-12-03 15:32:00   100            1
2012-12-03 15:32:00   101            1
```

I've found solutions having a separate time table with the full serie of timestamps, but I would much prefer to solve this in the query alone. Is this possible?

Comment: LEFT-join with a calendar table, which can be generated by generate_series (min(ts), max(ts))

Comment: @wildplasser: You should make that an answer.

Comment: I was working on it ... Including (nested!) CTEs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path = tmp;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS channel1m CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE channel1m (
  zts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  zitemid BIGINT,
  zvalue BIGINT
);

-- in which a row may be inserted each minute, per zitemid, as follows:

INSERT INTO channel1m(zts, zitemid, zvalue) VALUES
 ('2012-12-03 15:29:00',   100,            1)
,('2012-12-03 15:30:00',   100,            2)
,('2012-12-03 15:30:00',   101,            0)
,('2012-12-03 15:32:00',   100,            1)
,('2012-12-03 15:32:00',   101,            1)
        ;

        -- CTE to the rescue!!!
WITH cal AS (
        WITH mm AS (
                SELECT MIN(xx.zts) AS minmin, MAX(xx.zts) AS maxmax
                 FROM channel1m xx)
        SELECT generate_series(mm.minmin , mm.maxmax , '1 min'::interval) AS stamp
        FROM mm
        )
, ite AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT zitemid AS zitemid
        FROM channel1m
        )
SELECT cal.stamp
        , ite.zitemid
        , tab.zvalue
FROM cal
JOIN ite ON 1=1 -- Note: this is a cartesian product of the {time,id} -domains
LEFT JOIN channel1m tab ON tab.zts = cal.stamp AND tab.zitemid = ite.zitemid
ORDER BY stamp ASC
        ;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.channel1m
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
NOTICE:  table "channel1m" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
        stamp        | zitemid | zvalue 
---------------------+---------+--------
 2012-12-03 15:29:00 |     101 |       
 2012-12-03 15:29:00 |     100 |      1
 2012-12-03 15:30:00 |     100 |      2
 2012-12-03 15:30:00 |     101 |      0
 2012-12-03 15:31:00 |     100 |       
 2012-12-03 15:31:00 |     101 |       
 2012-12-03 15:32:00 |     100 |      1
 2012-12-03 15:32:00 |     101 |      1
(8 rows)
```

Comment: I was missing that cartesian product while trying to tackle a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You will need: table with all `itemId`, and a (pseudo)table with all required dates.

You probably have the table with all distinct `itemId`. Lets call it `item_table`.

Pseudo-table with dates you can get with `generate_series('start_date','end_date', interval '1 minute')`. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html).

The query:

```
SELECT gs.ts, it.itemId, ch1m.value
FROM item_table it
CROSS JOIN generate_series('start_date','end_date', interval '1 minute') gs(ts)
LEFT JOIN channel1m ch1m ON it.itemId = ch1m.itemId 
                         AND gs.ts = ch1m.ts
```

Replace `'start_date','end_date'` with desired values or get them from sub query.

This query:

1) Builds all pairs of item-time via `CROSS JOIN`

2) Gets the `value` via `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

I think the most readable way is to build a series of table expressions. A cross join between minutes and item ID numbers will give you every combination.

```
with all_minutes as (
  select ('2012-12-03 15:29'::timestamp + 
           (n || ' minute')::interval)::timestamp as ts
  from generate_series(0,10) n
),
item_ids as (
  select distinct itemid from channel1m
),
all_items_and_minutes as (
  select all_minutes.ts, item_ids.itemid from all_minutes cross join item_ids
)
select all_items_and_minutes.ts, all_items_and_minutes.itemId, channel1m.value
from all_items_and_minutes 
left join channel1m 
       on all_items_and_minutes.ts = channel1m.ts
      and all_items_and_minutes.itemid = channel1m.itemid
order by all_items_and_minutes.ts, all_items_and_minutes.itemid
```

You can replace the timestamp literals with SELECT statements to get the actual range you need. If you have a different table that contains all the unique item id numbers, you *might* be better off selecting from *that* table instead of selecting distinct values from the channel1m table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`time_bucket`](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/api#time_bucket) or `date_trunc` to create bucket boundaries.
2. Use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to generate empty buckets for your timeframe.
3. Use `UNION` to merge empty time bucket dataset with your data.
4. Use `DISTINCT ON` to pick unique rows per each time bucket, preferring those with data.

Example:

```
WITH
  timeseries_data AS (
    SELECT
      time_bucket(interval '5 minutes', started_at) time_bucket_start,
      count(distinct v1.value) unique_row_count
    FROM
      probe_execution pe1
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT value
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(pe1.result)
    ) v1
    WHERE
      pe1.probe_id = 8 AND
      pe1.result_count > 0 AND
      pe1.started_at > now() - interval '1 day' AND
      pe1.ended_at < now()
    GROUP BY time_bucket_start
    UNION
    SELECT
      gs1 time_bucket_start,
      0 unique_row_count
    FROM
      generate_series(
        time_bucket(interval '5 minutes', now() - interval '1 day'),
        time_bucket(interval '5 minutes', now()),
        interval '1 minute'
      ) as gs1
  )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (td1.time_bucket_start)
  td1.time_bucket_start,
  td1.unique_row_count
FROM timeseries_data td1
ORDER BY td1.time_bucket_start, td1.unique_row_count DESC
```